# InAppBrowser Not Showing Keyboard [Cordova 2.3.0]

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

I'm using the new InAppBrowser by Cordova 2.3.0. 
There are some issues related to it.

First : When I click on the address bar to change the url, the keyboard isn't displayed [I run it on Android].

It only works when I click for a long time inside the textbox & choose select all , copy & paste ... then the keyboard is displayed [ & sometimes even when I do this it's not displayed].

Second: When I open a pdf file from the browser, it doesn't open ... Why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The PDF issue can be fixed by setting the bridge mode to iframe

the cordova issue can be found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2102?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)