# InAppBrowser Not Showing Keyboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

Ok,

So I guess I have a lame question, but does the Cordova 2.3 InAppBrowser allow the user to change the URL? When I set the option 'location=yes' I see the address bar in both IOS and Android in my app, but when I tap on it, no keyboard to change the URL.

I found this:
[InAppBrowser Not Showing Keyboard [Cordova 2.3.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303397/inappbrowser-not-showing-keyboard-cordova-2-3-0)

I think he is having the same problem. Am I missing something?

I am using Phonegap-Build, Cordova 2.3, jQuery 1.9.1, Jquery Mobile 1.3 RC1

Thanks!

~Red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in the PhoneGap  Google Group. It is no. According to the admins there:

> "Nope, InAppBrowser is designed to be a viewer only."

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en%3Fhl%3Den&fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/Il6wQ_qNm70